# hibernate query returns only first character of string

Tags: hibernate, named-query

When I run a query like this in oracle 10g using sqldeveloper, it runs fine.

```
select 'Canada' as "country", emp.name as "name" from emp.
```

Gives me the name and country.
When  I run it in hibernate as a named query, I get only 'C' instead of 'Canada' for "country".

Why is this so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
select cast('Canada' as varchar2(100)) as "country", emp.name as "name" from emp
```

Comment: interesting! it also worked for me! thanks! but why do we need to do this cast solution, if it works perfectly when we run the query? what's the difference?

Comment: @periback2 this answers the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873201/hibernate-native-query-char3-column