# strange hibernate createSQLQuery returns a CHAR|Character but String

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate `createSQLQuery`, but it returns only first char.

```
tableName = 'select code, name from airports where excludeFromSearch = 0 order by name';
s.createSQLQuery(tableName).list();
```

I am using:

- Mysql
- hibernate 3.2

**Snapshot:**

[image]

I have googled [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343355/hibernate-query-returns-only-first-character-of-string),[forum.hibernate](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2441556),[atlassian](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2220)

**UPDATE:** i have also checked all hibernate query log and even mysql query log both are same.

```
`code char(3)`  // <strike>might</strike> must cause problem as in screen shot
name varchar(100)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate native query - char(3) column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873201/hibernate-native-query-char3-column)

Answer (score 6):

Have you tryied to set Scalar to your request?

```
StringType stringTypeInstance = StringType.class.newInstance();

String tableName = 'select code, name from airports where excludeFromSearch = 0 order by name';

List<Object[]> result = s.createSQLQuery(tableName)
    .addScalar("code",stringTypeInstance)
    .addScalar("name",stringTypeInstance )
    .list();
```

Answer (score 2):

First, try to fire the query that is generated by hibernate, on the database, and then try to match the results. If the query on database is also returning the same result, then check your table definition, the code is really string or something else.

And better option for writing queries that to SQL queries will be to write them, in the hbm file, and then define return properties in it, that will help you a lot, as then u will be able to covert the output into desired objects, not the array of object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple convert in SQL statement.

> `select convert(varchar, Name) from Person`

Problem exists in older versions of Hibernate when char is autowired to Character column value.
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2304