# JPA 2.0 - NVARCHAR in native query

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-server-2008-r2, jpa-2.0, nvarchar

The project that I'm working on has the following setup: JPA 2.0 (Hibernate 4 implementation) and SQL Server 2008 R2.

I need to select some data from an SQL view. In order to do this I use a native query, but I ran into some problems with the NVARCHAR fields. Basically, when using this piece of code:

```
 String sql = "SELECT v.text_field as address FROM SOME_CUSTOM_VIEW v
 Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql,"ItemDetailsMapping");
 List<Object[]> result = q.getResultList();
```

The ItemDetailsMapping is declared like:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "ItemDetailsMapping", columns = { @ColumnResult(name = "address") })
```

I get an exception saying:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC     type: -9; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
```

Type -9 is actually the NVARCHAR type, which we are extensively using throughout the application and it works perfectly when we are using non-native queries. Why is it not working with native queries? I even used a custom dialect and registered the type, but it's still not working.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to associate the data type `NVARCHAR` to `String`.When using Hibernate via Session interface, you can explcitly set a type of result with `addScalar()` instead (also accessible via `unwrap()` in JPA 2.0):

So modify your code as below,

```
 String sql = "SELECT v.text_field as address FROM SOME_CUSTOM_VIEW v"
 Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql,"ItemDetailsMapping");
 q.unwrap(SQLQuery.class).addScalar("address ", StringType.INSTANCE);
 List<Object[]> result = q.getResultList();
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4873520/507864) for more information.

(Edit 7/1/15 -- Added quotation mark for clarity)

Comment: Thank you. I'll give a try and see how it goes.

Comment: It seems  the method `addScalar` do not exist anymore

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
String myquery = "select cast(t2.name as varchar) column_name from sys.objects t1 inner join sys.columns t2 on t2.object_id = t1.object_id"+ 
" left join sys.indexes t3 on t3.object_id = t1.object_id and t3.is_unique = 1 left join sys.index_columns t4 on t4.object_id = t1.object_id and t4.index_id = t3.index_id and t4.column_id = t2.column_id where (upper(t1.type) = 'U' or upper(t1.type) = 'V') and upper(schema_name(t1.schema_id)) = 'dbo' and upper(t1.name) = 'TEST'";
```