# Hibernate Native Query Result list Datatype mismatch

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying to get run a native query to get a resultset in hibernate. I am able to get List from the query.

```
Query nativeQuery = manager.createNativeQuery("select name, country_cd from fresher");
List<Object[]> amount =  nativeQuery.getResultList()
for(Object[] e : amount)
{
     for(Object n : e)
        {           
          if(n != null)
               System.out.print(n + " \t " +  n.getClass());
        }
}
```

The expected Result is : Joe, US

The Result of this is like :

class java.lang.String -- > Joe
class java.lang.Character -- > U

In the database, **name** (VARCHAR2(100)) and **country_cd** (CHAR(2 BYTE)) are defined in table fresher.

As per [hibernate database types](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch08.html), the char(2byte) is taken as java.lang.Character

How can I retrieve the data of type char(2b) as String ?

Note : I cannot use a result class/entity since the results could be dynamic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate native query - char(3) column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873201/hibernate-native-query-char3-column)

Comment: Thanks axtavt!                    
I modified the query as follows : 'select cast(country_cd  as VARCHAR2(200))  as country_cd from fresher'