# Hibernate Native SQL returns partial character insted of String

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Native hibernate query to get data from database.

here is my code

```
String sqlQuery="select * from testTable"
Query query = informixSessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .createSQLQuery(sql);
List test=query.list();
```

It executes fine but when i checks the value in list i found that it takes the datatype as `character` insted of `String`, It displays first `character` only. please help

Comment: `i found that it takes the datatype as character insted of String` ?? Where it is taking ?

Comment: i gets the result in list in that list there on every column where the String should be there. it gives me character

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873201/hibernate-native-query-char3-column

Comment: thanks @axtavt i think its solution for Oracle I am using Informix. I have same problem but that solution didn't worked for me

Comment: I do have the same issue- hibernate get returns partial string, i have used 'text' datatype in my mysql db is there any possibilities of issue due to usage of datatype text?