# How to specify return types of columns in NativeQuery

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

How to specify return types of columns in NativeQuery? Now Query returns BigInteger but I want to map it to Long.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

Object[] o = (Object[]) entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT x FROM y WHERE id = :id").setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
(Long) o[0];
```

Leads to

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot
>   be cast to java.lang.Long

In Hibernate there is `addScalar` function but in javax.persistence there it is not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a result class you will get the return type of the JDBC driver for that column, which can be different dependent on the datastore in use. This is a native (SQL) query so dependent totally on the JDBC driver (as opposed to the JPA implementation)

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any solutions but this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227578/does-jpa-have-an-equivalent-to-hibernate-sqlquery-addscalar) seems to provide a workaround to this. For e.g.

```
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT PHONE_ID FROM PHONE WHERE PHONE_NUMBER = '40101930'");

    ((SQLQuery)((HibernateQuery) query).getHibernateQuery()).addScalar("PHONE_ID", StandardBasicTypes.LONG);
    Long phoneId = (Long) query.getSingleResult();
```