# EntityManager.createNativeQuery returning list of objects instead of list of BigDecimal when using Pagination

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, pagination, entitymanager

I am trying to use Pagination with `EntityManager.createNativeQuery()`. Below is the skeleton code that I am using:

```
var query = em.createNativeQuery("select distinct id from ... group by ... having ...");
List<BigDecimal> results = query
        .setMaxResults(pageSize)
        .setFirstResult(pageNumber * pageSize)
        .getResultList();
```

When `pageNumber` is 0 (first page), I get the expected List of BigDecimals:

[image]

But as soon as `pageNumber` > 0 (example, second page), I get a List of Objects, and each object in this list seems to contain two BigDecimals, the first of which contains the value from the db, and the second BigDecimal seems to be the position of this row.

[image]

and obviously I get this exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class java.math.BigDecimal

Can someone please explain this discrepancy, and how this can be fixed to always return a List of BigDecimals? Thank you.

**Update-1** : I have created [a sample project](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/spring-data-native-query-pagination-issue-oracle) to reproduce this issue. I was able to reproduce this issue only with an Oracle database. With H2 database, it worked fine, and I consistently got a list of BigDecimals irrelevant of the page number.

**Update-2** : I have also created [a sample project with H2](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/spring-data-native-query-pagination-issue-h2) where it works without this issue.

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @SternK Hibernate Version 5.2.18

Comment: Try to use BigInteger instead

Comment: @GuilhermeAlencar Changing `List<BigDecimal>` to `List<BigInteger> results`, unfortunately, doesn't change anything. What is strange is that the `result` object still has the same BigDecimals as in the second screenshot above.

Comment: My suggestion is to debug the result of getResultList before assigning to your list. To see if what is wrong is the unmarshalling to your object or the consult itself.

Comment: I tried doing that already, and there is a lot of nested code with aop involved, and it was a bit difficult to find out the point where this was happening in the hibernate/spring/oracle libraries.

Comment: @SrikanthReddyLingala could you please provide a full query what you try to run via `createNativeQuery`

Comment: I have a feeling that your query is not right

Comment: You have probably noticed it already, but I am trying to execute a native query. The same query when executed from sql editor or even from the code, for the first page, works fine. Below is the query. I have replaced the table/schema/column names here with some random names to hide business sensitive names: `SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME GROUP BY ID HAVING MAX (COALESCE (FILTER_DATE, TO_DATE('31.12.9999', 'dd.mm.yyyy'))) < ?1`

Comment: FYI If ID is primary key there is no need to distinct and group by. Try to replace your query for SELECT ID FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME WHERE TO_DATE('31.12.9999', 'dd.mm.yyyy'))) < ?1

Comment: ID is not primary key. ID is not the actual column I am querying for. As mentioned in my previous post, I just replaced the name to hide any potentially sensitive information.

Comment: Column name is no sensitive data rsrs. But ok, try to run your query directly on db and see if it's returning exactly what you expect.

Comment: what data base do you use? what data type math id in db ?

Comment: It's an Oracle DB. Data type of column being queried is `NUMBER`

Comment: @EvgeniyKalashnikov I have updated the post with a sample project that I have created to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trails with different versions of different spring libraries, I was finally able to figure out the issue. In one of my attempts, the issue seems to have disappeared, as soon as I updated the spring-data-commons library from v2.1.5.RELEASE to v2.1.6.RELEASE. I looked up the [changelog of this release](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/changelog.txt), and [this bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1482), which is related to [this bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1552) in spring-data-commons, is the root cause of this issue. I was able to fix the issue after upgrading the spring-data-commons library.

Comment: What hibernate version do you have in this new spring data version? What exactly hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: Hibernate version `5.2.18.Final`, and hibernate dialect `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`

Comment: I am afraid that this issue still with you. Actually your query in the `CustomerRepository` is irrelevant to this problem. You can simplify it to `@Query(value = "SELECT SHOP_ID FROM CUSTOMER", nativeQuery = true)
Page<BigDecimal> findContractsToBeDeleted(Pageable pageable);`

Comment: The only thing that is matter: your query returns one column, but due to query modification related to the pagination this fact is changed and two columns are returned as it stated in my answer.

Comment: That is the problem. People find it hard to believe that the oracle dialect actually results in an extra column being returned in addition to all of the columns that were selected.

Answer (score 6):

The problem that you are running into is that your OracleDialect adds a column to its selected ResultSet. It wraps the query that you are running as discussed in SternK's answer.

If you were using the Hibernate SessionFactory and the Session interfaces, then the function that you would be looking for would be the "addScalar" method. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an implementation in pure JPA (see the question asked here: [Does JPA have an equivalent to Hibernate SQLQuery.addScalar()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227578/does-jpa-have-an-equivalent-to-hibernate-sqlquery-addscalar)).

I would expect your current implementation to work just fine in DB2, H2, HSQL, Postgres, MySQL (and a few other DB engines). However, in Oracle, it adds a row-number column to the ResultSet which means that Hibernate gets 2 columns from the ResultSet. Hibernate does not implement any query parsing in this case, which means that it simply parses the ResultSet into your List. Since it gets 2 values, it converts them into an Object[] rather than a BigDecimal.

As a caveat, relying on the JDBC driver to provide the expected-data-type is a bit dangerous, since Hibernate will ask the JDBC driver which data-type it suggests. In this case, it suggests a BigDecimal, but under certain conditions and certain implementations would be allowed to return a Double or some other type.

You have a couple options then.

1. You can modify your oracle-dialect (as SternK) suggests. This will take advantage of an alternate oracle-paging implementation.
2. If you are not opposed to having hibnerate-specific aspects in your JPA implementation, then you can take advantage of additional hibernate functions that are not offered in the JPA standard. (See the following code...)

   ```
   List<BigDecimal> results = entitymanager.createNativeQuery("select distinct id from ... group by ... having ...")
           .unwrap(org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class)
           .addScalar("id", BigDecimalType.INSTANCE)
           .getResultList();
   System.out.println(results);
   ```

This does have the advantage of explicitly telling hibnerate, that you are only interested in the "id" column of your ResultSet, and that hibernate needs to explicitly convert to the returned object to a BigDecimal, should the JDBC-driver decide that a different type would be more appropriate as a default.

Answer (score 4):

The root cause of your problem in the way how the pagination implemented in your hibernate [oracle dialect](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/Oracle9iDialect.java#L29).

There are two cases:

1. When we have `setFirstResult(0)` the following sql will be generated:

```sql
-- setMaxResults(5).setFirstResult(0)
select * from (
  select test_id from TST_MY_TEST -- this is your initial query
) 
where rownum <= 5;
```

As you can see, this query returns exactly the same columns list as your initial query, and therefore you do not have problem with this case.

2. When we set `setFirstResult` in not `0` value the following sql will be generated:

```sql
-- setMaxResults(5).setFirstResult(2)
select * from (
   select row_.*, rownum rownum_ 
   from (
      select test_id from TST_MY_TEST -- this is your initial query
   ) row_ 
   where rownum <= 5
) 
where rownum_ > 2
```

As you can see, this query returns the columns list with additional `rownum_` column, and therefore you do have the problem with casting this result set to the `BigDecimal`.

**Solution**

If you use Oracle 12c R1 (12.1) or higher you can override this behavior in your dialect using new [row limiting clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering) in this way:

```java
import org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.AbstractLimitHandler;
import org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.LimitHandler;
import org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.LimitHelper;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.RowSelection;


public class MyOracleDialect extends Oracle12cDialect
{
   private static final AbstractLimitHandler LIMIT_HANDLER = new AbstractLimitHandler() {
      @Override
      public String processSql(String sql, RowSelection selection) {
         final boolean hasOffset = LimitHelper.hasFirstRow(selection);
         final StringBuilder pagingSelect = new StringBuilder(sql.length() + 50);
         pagingSelect.append(sql);
         
         /*
            see the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABHFGAA
            (Restrictions on the row_limiting_clause)
            You cannot specify this clause with the for_update_clause.
          */
         if (hasOffset) {
            pagingSelect.append(" OFFSET ? ROWS");
         }
         pagingSelect.append(" FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY");
         return pagingSelect.toString();
      }

      @Override
      public boolean supportsLimit() {
         return true;
      }
   };

   public MyOracleDialect()
   {
   }
   
   @Override
   public LimitHandler getLimitHandler() {
      return LIMIT_HANDLER;
   }
}
```

and then use it.

```xml
<property name="hibernate.dialect">com.me.MyOracleDialect</property>
```

For my test data set for the following query:

```java
NativeQuery query = session.createNativeQuery(
   "select test_id from TST_MY_TEST"
).setMaxResults(5).setFirstResult(2);

List<BigDecimal> results = query.getResultList();
```

I got:

```
Hibernate: 
/* dynamic native SQL query */
select test_id  from TST_MY_TEST
OFFSET ? ROWS FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY

val = 3
val = 4
val = 5
val = 6
val = 7
```

P.S. See also [HHH-12087](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/issues/HHH-12087)

P.P.S I simplified my implementation of the `AbstractLimitHandler` by removing checking presents `FOR UPDATE` clause. I think we will not have nothing good in this case and with this checking.

For example for the following case:

```
NativeQuery query = session.createNativeQuery(
   "select test_id from TST_MY_TEST FOR UPDATE OF test_id"
).setMaxResults(5).setFirstResult(2);
```

hibernate (with `Oracle12cDialect`) will generate the following sql:

```sql
/* dynamic native SQL query */
select * from (
  select
     row_.*,
     rownum rownum_ 
  from (
     select test_id from TST_MY_TEST -- initial sql without FOR UPDATE clause
  ) row_ 
  where rownum <= 5
) 
where rownum_ > 2
FOR UPDATE OF test_id -- moved for_update_clause
```

As you can see, hibernate tries to fix query by moving `FOR UPDATE` to the end of the query. But anyway, we will get:

```
ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

I've simulated your consult and everything works fine. I've used `DataJpaTest` to instance entityManager for me, `h2` memory database and `JUnit 5` to run the test. See below:

```
@Test
public void shouldGetListOfSalaryPaginated() {
    // given
    Person alex = new Person("alex");
    alex.setSalary(BigDecimal.valueOf(3305.33));
    Person john = new Person("john");
    john.setSalary(BigDecimal.valueOf(33054.10));
    Person ana = new Person("ana");
    ana.setSalary(BigDecimal.valueOf(1223));
    
    entityManager.persist(alex);
    entityManager.persist(john);
    entityManager.persist(ana);
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.clear();

    // when
    List<BigDecimal> found = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT salary FROM person").setMaxResults(2).setFirstResult(2*1).getResultList();

    // then
    Assertions.assertEquals(found.size(), 1);
    Assertions.assertEquals(found.get(0).longValue(), 1223L);
}
```

I suggest that you review your native query. It's preferable that you use Criteria API instead and let native queries for extreme cases like complex consults.

**Update**

After the author posted the project, I could reproduce the problem and it was related to the oracle dialect. For unknown reason the query which is running for the second call is: `select * from ( select row_.*, rownum rownum_ from ( SELECT c.SHOP_ID FROM CUSTOMER c ) row_ where rownum <= ?) where rownum_ > ?`, and that's why this is generating a bug, because it's querying 2 columns instead of only one. The undesired one is this `rownum`. For other dialects there is no such problem.

I suggest you try other oracle dialect version and whether none of them work, my final tip is try to do the pagination yourself.

Comment: The reason I use native query is because of a complex query that I have to execute. The behaviour that the query returns one type of results on the first page, and another type of results from the second page on is quite puzzling, especially if such behaviour is not documented, and not reproducible with other queries.

Comment: I have reproduced exactly the same behaviour you have exposed (querying natively a list of big decimal paginated through entity manager). It's working properly for first or second page. I am telling you the problem is on your query or maybe in the data stored, if you wish more from me or anyone you should provide more information. That's it for me, good luck!

Comment: My last guess is that maybe the scale of your column database is not matching with your bigdecimal mapping by hibernate and MAYBE this is causing this mess.

Comment: I appreicate your effort and support. Unfortunately, nothing seems to have helped so far. I have created a sample project to reproduce this issue. You can find it here: https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/spring-data-native-query-pagination-issue-oracle

Comment: I have also added a sample project with H2, and it works perfectly fine with H2. Link to the project is in the issue description above.

Comment: Yeah, It's was a good idea. I took a look and for unknown reason this query is running for the second call: `select * from ( select row_.*, rownum rownum_ from ( SELECT c.SHOP_ID FROM CUSTOMER c ) row_ where rownum <= ?) where rownum_ > ?`, and that's why this is generating a bug, because it's querying 2 columns instead of only  one. The undesired one is this rownum. You will have to create another class to represent this payload (with fields like rownum, data,...) and your repository will return something like Page<MyPayload>.

Comment: My query was even simpler than yours:     `@Query(value = "SELECT c.SHOP_ID " +
            "FROM CUSTOMER c ", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<BigDecimal> findContractsToBeDeleted(Pageable pageable);`

Comment: `You will have to create another class to represent this payload` I tried that already. Didn't help either.

Comment: The issue here is the database dialect. This issue cannot be reproduced using H2 (or hsql, or mysql, or db2, or postgres) - it is a function of oracle. Testing using any other dialect or database will be counterproductive and lead to false conclusions and discussion, as the code provided in the initial question will work in virtually every database flavor except for oracle (which is what he is using here).

Comment: Yeah Nathan. Thank you. When I answered I didn't have all information. After some debate, the author had a good ideia of posting the project ;)